# How can I keep a tally of the count associated with each type of record?

Tags: r

I have some data:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(17888, 17888, 17888, 17888, 
17889, 17889, 17891, 17891, 17891, 17891, 17891, 17892, 17894
), class = "Date"), type = structure(c(4L, 6L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("aborted-live-lead", 
"conversation-archived", "conversation-auto-archived", "conversation-auto-archived-store-offline-or-busy", 
"conversation-claimed", "conversation-created", "conversation-dropped", 
"conversation-restarted", "conversation-transfered", "cs-transfer-connected", 
"cs-transfer-ended", "cs-transfer-failed", "cs-transfer-initiate", 
"cs-transfer-request", "getnotified-requested", "lead-created", 
"lead-expired"), class = "factor"), count = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

It looks like this:

```
> head(dat)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  date       type                                             count
  <date>     <fct>                                            <int>
1 2018-12-23 conversation-auto-archived-store-offline-or-busy     1
2 2018-12-23 conversation-created                                 1
3 2018-12-23 getnotified-requested                                1
4 2018-12-23 lead-created                                         1
5 2018-12-24 conversation-archived                                3
6 2018-12-24 conversation-claimed                                 1
```

For each unique `type` value, there is an associated `count` per day.

How can I count all of the values of each `type` (regardless of the date) and list them in a two-column data frame (in a format like this):

```
type                   count
------                 ------
conversation-created   10
conversation-archived  4
lead-created           2
...
```

The reason for this is to show an overall count of each event type over the entire date range.

I presume that I have to use the `select()` function from `dplyr` but I am sure I am missing something.

This is what I have so far - it sums every value in the `count` column which isn't what I want as I want it broken down by day:

```
dat %>%
  select(type, count) %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(count)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: you need to `group_by`, i.e. `df %>% group_by(type) %>% count()`

Comment: Perfect! I changed my code to `dat %>% group_by(type) %>% summarise(count = sum(count))`. `count()` alone doesn't work as it counts the number of events; I want to keep count of the associated `count` value, hence why I use `summarise(count = sum(count))`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a combination of `group_by` and `summarize` with `sum` does the job:

```
dat %>% group_by(type) %>% summarise(count = sum(count))
# A tibble: 8 x 2
#   type                                             count
#   <fct>                                            <int>
# 1 conversation-archived                                7
# 2 conversation-auto-archived                           1
# 3 conversation-auto-archived-store-offline-or-busy     1
# 4 conversation-claimed                                 3
# 5 conversation-created                                 3
# 6 conversation-restarted                               1
# 7 getnotified-requested                                1
# 8 lead-created                                         1
```

There is no need for `select` as `summarize` will drop all the other variables anyway. Or perhaps you are confusing `select` with `group_by`, which is what we want in this case - to summarize those values of `count` where `type` takes the same value.